# CSS menu stopped working - /function/ is undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that has been working for quite some time, but in the last few months the dropdown menu has failed.  The URL is [OPTSC.COM](http://www.optsc.com).  The "About Us" menu should trigger a javascript function that toggles the visibility style attribute of the element.  The functions to toggle the drop-down menu are:

```
function hideDivs(){
    if(current_sub!=''){
        document.getElementById(current_sub).style.visibility = "hidden";
        current_sub='';
    }           
}
function showdivmenu(sub_menu){
    current_sub=sub_menu;
    hideDivs();
    document.getElementById(sub_menu).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

They called as such:

```
<div class="mainmenudiv" onmouseout="hideDivs();" onmouseover="showdivmenu('menudropdown2');">
    <a href="/aboutus/" title="About the Ottawa Physiotherapy & Sport Clinic">About Us</a>
    <div id="menudropdown2">
        <img src="/_images/body/header/menu/dropdown/fade.jpg" alt="" />
        <a href="/aboutus/ourteam/" title="About our <?= $location_name ?> Physiotherapists">Our Team</a>
        <a href="/aboutus/ourfacilities/" title="Our Ottawa area physiotherapy facilities located in Barrhaven, Westboro and Orleans">Our Facilities</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why it stopped working? I inherited the code and am horrid with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Console tab in Chrome Developer Tools (you are using those right?) and you'll immediately see you have an error in functions.js at line 41:

```
var strConfirm = "Are you sure you want to delete '"   sName   "'?";
```

You are missing string concatenation here. Change it to:

```
var strConfirm = "Are you sure you want to delete '" + sName + "'?";
```

And then use the Developer Tools to see if there are any other issues after fixing that one. Not sure if this one issue will fix all of your problems, but it should get you started.

Comment: Thank you.  It appears several "+" symbols were stripped out somehow.  I will definitely be using the Chrome Tools from now on.